# Enable/Disable <p:commandButton> through two <p:selectOneMenu>

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, selectonemenu, commandbutton

I need to enable a commandButton when two required selectOneMenu components have not empty values

**This is my view:**

```xml
<p:selectOneMenu converter="omnifaces.SelectItemsConverter" id="countries" required="true" value="#{countryBean.selectedCountry}">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{msg['choose.option']}" />
    <f:selectItems value="#{countryBean.countries}" var="country" itemLabel="#{country.name}" />
    <f:ajax listener="#{countryBean.changeCountry}" render="cities" update="findPeopleButton" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
<p:selectOneMenu converter="omnifaces.SelectItemsConverter" id="cities" required="true" value="#{countryBean.city}">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{msg['choose.option']}" />
    <f:selectItems value="#{countryBean.cities}" var="city" itemLabel="#{city.name}" />
    <f:ajax listener="#{countryBean.verifyRequiredFields}" update="findPeopleButton" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
<p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-search"
    disabled="#{countryBean.disablePeopleButton}"
    id="findPeopleButton"
    onclick="peopleDialog.show()" />
```

I disabled the button when my view loads, then when I select values for each selectOneMenu the button enables but after that when I set an empty value of some selectOneMenu I get a required validation error message and the button keeps enabled

**This is my backing bean:**

```
private Country country; // +getter+setter
private City city; // +getter+setter
private List<Country> countries; // +getter
private List<City> cities; // +getter
private boolean disablePeopleButton; // +getter+setter

@EJB
private CountryService countryService;

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    disablePeopleButton = true;
    countries = countryService.getCountries();
}

public void changeCountry() {
    cities = countryService.getCities(country);
}

public void verifyRequiredFields() {
    if (country != null && city != null) {
        disablePeopleButton = false;
    } else {
        disablePeopleButton = true;
    }
}
```

What can I do to fix it?

Comment: Instead of checking whether the objects are null in `verifyRequiredFields()`, you should check to see if they have a valid value. You should also use `<f:ajax event="valueChange" listener="#{countryBean.verifyRequiredFields}" update="findPeopleButton" />` on both selectOneMenus in my opinion.

Comment: Ok @LucasPate but my real problem is that when I select the default option (choose item) my selectOneMenu throws a required validation error message

Comment: why not just remove all `required` attributes. if not both are selected the button is disabled anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```html
<h:form>
    <p:selectOneMenu id="countries"
        converter="omnifaces.SelectItemsConverter"
        value="#{countryBean.selectedCountry}">
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{msg['choose.option']}"/>
        <f:selectItems value="#{countryBean.countries}" var="country"
            itemLabel="#{country.name}" />
        <p:ajax listener="#{countryBean.changeCountry()}" 
                update="cities findPeopleButton" />
    </p:selectOneMenu>
    <p:selectOneMenu id="cities"
        converter="omnifaces.SelectItemsConverter"
        value="#{countryBean.city}">
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{msg['choose.option']}" />
        <f:selectItems value="#{countryBean.cities}" var="city"
            itemLabel="#{city.name}" />
        <p:ajax update="findPeopleButton" />
    </p:selectOneMenu>
    <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-search"
        disabled="#{empty countryBean.city}"
        id="findPeopleButton" onclick="peopleDialog.show()" />
</h:form>
```

and this:

```java
    private Country selectedCountry; // +getter+setter
    private City city; // +getter+setter
    private List<Country> countries; // +getter
    private List<City> cities; // +getter

    @EJB
    private CountryService countryService;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        countries = countryService.getCountries();
    }

    public void changeCountry() {
        if (selectedCountry != null) {
            cities = countryService.getCities(selectedCountry);
        }
        city = null;
    }
```

Don't know how this correlates with your issues but you were using `#{countryBean.selectedCountry}` in Facelets code while only having `country` in the bean. You also used `render` and `update` on `<f:ajax>` which has only the former, while `<p:ajax>` has only the latter.

Answer (score 0):

use `itemValue=""` in both `p:selectOneMenu`

```
<p:selectOneMenu converter="omnifaces.SelectItemsConverter" id="countries" required="true" value="#{countryBean.selectedCountry}">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{msg['choose.option']}" itemValue=""/>
    <f:selectItems value="#{countryBean.countries}" var="country" itemLabel="#{country.name}" />
    <f:ajax listener="#{countryBean.changeCountry}" render="cities" update="findPeopleButton" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
<p:selectOneMenu converter="omnifaces.SelectItemsConverter" id="cities" required="true" value="#{countryBean.city}">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{msg['choose.option']}" itemValue=""/>
    <f:selectItems value="#{countryBean.cities}" var="city" itemLabel="#{city.name}" />
    <f:ajax listener="#{countryBean.verifyRequiredFields}" update="findPeopleButton" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
<p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-search"
    disabled="#{countryBean.disablePeopleButton}"
    id="findPeopleButton"
    onclick="peopleDialog.show()" />
```